# Migrating from android-annotation 2.7.1 to 3.3.1 break app

Tags: android-annotations

As i said in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991656/what-its-the-first-the-annotated-class-egg-or-used-class-chicken/30991915) i "migrate" eclipse/maven code of android-annotation app 2.7.1 to gradle in 3.3.1 but when i open tab "devices" (the bottom middle) it crash but if i used [store app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pandaos.smartconfig) its doesn't and i suppouse because some change from 2.7.1 to 3.3.1

I upload [code](https://github.com/josejuanmontiel/SmartConfig)

and crash in com.pandaos.smartconfig.DevicesFragment

```
@AfterViews
void afterViews() {
    devices_list_listview.setAdapter(deviceListAdapter);
    devices_recent_listview.setAdapter(recentDeviceListAdapter);
}
```

finish.

Some idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the stack trace you are seeing?

Comment: Sorry i need to see it again ... :) http://pastebin.ca/3042415 its the log

Comment: I read the log and i pretty sure it is unrelated to AA. The problem is you are trying to use a tab with tag `null`, which does not exist in the `FragmentTabHost`.

Comment: I checked your repo. I think you are using bad layout id [here](https://github.com/josejuanmontiel/SmartConfig/blob/5a8464a5c2e22744603fa67a7ec888cf80e685b9/src/main/java/com/pandaos/smartconfig/DevicesFragment.java#L37). There could be other problems, though.

Comment: Well you are right... i fail to copy original code... :( and dont know why. Thanks for your time and sorry to thinks that upgrade version lib break code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As wondercsabo said, the original code wasn't copy correctly and there is no problem with version upgrade.

Thanks again wondercsabo